# Applying f for a part of list (MapAt is slow)

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, map

Suppose that there are 2000 stones **in a row**.
You should grind 1000 of them to make beads.
The time loads(making beads) for each stone are similar.
But which 1000 stones?

case1) the **first 1000** stones.

case2) Let `B = RandomSample[Range[2000], 1000]`.
Then, **all b-th** stones, where **b** denotes element of `B`.

If this is a problem of **real world**, then case1) is faster then case2), because
for case2),

1. You have to read the `B` every time after grinding a stone.
2. If the next stone to be processed is far away, it will take a long time to go there.
3. `B` is even not sorted by size.

But, if it was a problem of **mathematica,**

2000 stones in a row = a list of 2000 elements
grinding a stone = applying function to an element

The time loads for case1) and time loads for case2) should be similar in my opinion.

I experienced that
"**just because some elements of a list are positionally close, there is no particular advantage to processing(=applying function) them at once(or consecutively)**"

Also I believe that
"there is a fast mathematica code for case2) always, that takes silmilar time compared to case1)"

Am I thinking correctly?

If so, can you make a fast code for the following problem ?

For `L`, square(=apply `#^2&`) each b-th element of `L`.(leave other element unchanged)

```
L = Range[40000, 59999];
B = RandomSample[Range[20000], 10000];
```

My first trial was

```
MapAt[#^2&, L, {#}&/@B] //Timing
2.85938
```

which is never successful.

After some other trials, I realized that **MapAt is very slow, in all cases**.
The performance was so bad that I felt **MapAt should not be used in any case**.

Finally I succeeded to shortening the time(using **ReplacePart**) but it is not neat and I don't think my code is as fast as professional programmer's one.

***What skill do you use, when applying a function for a part of list? (faster!)***

Can you help me?

Comment: Much faster: `cres = lx; cres[[bx]] = lx[[bx]]*lx[[bx]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am sure this is not the fastest solution but it is 25 times faster.

```
lx = Range[40000, 59999];
bx = RandomSample[Range[20000], 10000];
ares = MapAt[#^2 &, lx, {#} & /@ bx] // Timing
bres = SubsetMap[#^2 &, lx, {#} & /@ bx] // Timing

ares[[2]] == bres[[2]]
```

> ```
> (*True*)
> ```

```
{First@ares, First@bres}
```

> ```
> {1.17001, 0.0468003}
> ```

Comment: Wow! SubsetMap is a new feature in V12! Thank you!

Comment: For this particular variation of the `SubsetMap` syntax, you are executing a `MapAt` at the subset of the positions that you have chosen somehow, so there is no mental gymnastics involved.

Comment: May I ask what if you were in mathematica V11 ?

Comment: Please edit this requirement in to your post. I don't have M11 so I cannot say for sure, but if I find another way I will update the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple more to add to Syed's & Alan's. The compiled version is much faster, if everything stays machine-size.  If you're doing this repeatedly, you could compile ahead of time (to C even).  You have to recompile if you change the function from `#^2`; and if the function to be applied is not compilable, then it obviously won't work well.

```
lx = Range[40000, 59999];
bx = RandomSample[Range[20000], 10000];
ares = MapAt[#^2 &, lx, {#} & /@ bx]; // AbsoluteTiming
bres = SubsetMap[#^2 &, lx, {#} & /@ bx]; // AbsoluteTiming
(cres = lx; Do[cres[[k]] = cres[[k]]^2, {k, bx}]); // AbsoluteTiming
dres = Compile[{{lx, _Integer, 1}, {bx, _Integer, 1}},
     Block[{dres = lx},
      Do[dres[[k]] = dres[[k]]^2, {k, bx}];
      dres
      ]
     ][lx, bx]; // AbsoluteTiming
(eres = lx; eres[[bx]] = eres[[bx]]^2); // AbsoluteTiming

ares == bres == cres == dres == eres
(*
  {0.633558, Null}
  {0.013454, Null}
  {0.006371, Null}
  {0.000657, Null}
  {0.000221, Null}  <-- Alan's is fastest
  True
*)
```

Comment: Note @Alan's depends on `B` or `bx` not having duplicate indices, which it doesn't in the problem given in the OP.

Comment: `FunctionCompile` beats them all, but there is an initial long compilation delay. I have posted the code as an extension of this answer.

Answer (score 7):

I just extended @Michael-E2 answer by including `FunctionCompile`:

```
lx = Range[40000, 59999];
bx = RandomSample[Range[20000], 10000];
ares = MapAt[#^2 &, lx, {#} & /@ bx]; // AbsoluteTiming
bres = SubsetMap[#^2 &, lx, {#} & /@ bx]; // AbsoluteTiming
(cres = lx; Do[cres[[k]] = cres[[k]]^2, {k, bx}]); // AbsoluteTiming
dres = Compile[{{lx, _Integer, 1}, {bx, _Integer, 1}}, 
     Block[{dres = lx}, Do[dres[[k]] = dres[[k]]^2, {k, bx}];
      dres]][lx, bx]; // AbsoluteTiming
(eres = lx; eres[[bx]] = eres[[bx]]^2); // AbsoluteTiming
ffun = FunctionCompile[
   Function[
    {Typed[lx, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["MachineInteger", 1]], 
     Typed[bx, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["MachineInteger", 1]]}, 
    Block[{fres = lx}, Do[fres[[k]] = fres[[k]]^2, {k, bx}]; fres]]];
fres = ffun[lx, bx]; // AbsoluteTiming

ares == bres == cres == dres == eres == fres

(*
  {1.29098,Null}
  {0.0542107,Null}
  {0.0229712,Null}
  {0.0005062,Null}
  {0.0001768,Null}
  {0.0000713,Null}
  True
*)
```

Comment: +1 because updating `fres` is so fast. Nice. I wonder how much the compile time should be counted. (The compile time is included in `dres`, but it's fairly negligible.)

Answer (score 4):

Another approach that is supported by the previous versions (`11.3` at least) is to create a list of functions which are either (`Identity` which doesn't touch the data or `fn` which apply your function) and then `MapThread` this list with `Construct`:

```
Block[{temp},

(* create a list of Identity function *)
temp = ConstantArray[Identity, Length[L]];

(* replace the positions with your function *)
temp[[B]] = #^2 &;

(* apply your list of function to your data (element-wise) *)
result = MapThread[Construct, {temp, L}];

] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {0.0161858, 800568} *)
```

Result:

```
result == SubsetMap[#^2 &, L, {#} & /@ B]
(* Out: True *)
```

Another benefit is the memory footprint (could vary):

```
MapAt[#^2 &, L, {#} & /@ B]; // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {1.2336, 1912832} *)

(* @Syed answer *)
SubsetMap[#^2 &, L, {#} & /@ B]; // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {0.0305638, 6541432} *)
```

which is around `2` and `8` times smaller respectively.

Notes:

- Minimum version `11.3` is because of `Construct`, if you happen to have an alternative, the minimum requirement would be lowered (although performance would be affected).
- This method could easily be extended to apply multiple functions.