# Extracting list structure from nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, built-in-symbols

Can we construct a function `f, g` in mathematica such that

For any list `L`,

`g[Flatten[L],f[L]]` becomes `L`.

More explanation :
`f[..]` outputs the structure of a given list `L` (nested structure)
`g[..,..]` restores original list `L`, from flattened list and the structure of the list.

I bet there is a built-in function or someone else already have made it.

This question is related with generalization of

[Applying f for a part of list (MapAt is slow)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264689/applying-f-for-a-part-of-list-mapat-is-slow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, g]
f = Identity;
g = Internal`CopyListStructure[#2, #] &;
```

***Example:***

```
list = {{1, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{{6, 7}}}, {{8, {{{9}}}}, {10, 11}}};

g[Flatten @ list, f @ list] == list
```

> ```
> True
> ```

***Note:*** `` Internal`CopyListStructure[arg1_, arg2_] `` requires `Length[Flatten @ arg1] == Length @ arg2`:

***Examples:***

```
Internal`CopyListStructure[{{a, {b, {{{{{c}}}}, d}}}}, {2, 3, 4, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{2, {3, {{{{{4}}}}, 1}}}}
> ```

```
Internal`CopyListStructure[{{a, {b, {c}}}}, {{x, y}, {r, s, t, {u}}, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{{x, y}, {{r, s, t, {u}}, {1}}}}
> ```

Comment: Always thank you!  I posted related problem here : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264838