# Simple, fast re-defining a part of 2D list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, replacement

```
A[[{2, 3, 5}]] = {97,98,99}
```

changes 2,3,5-th elements of A to 97,98,99 respectively.

Similary

```
A[[{2, 3, 5}]] = 100
```

changes 2,3,5-th elements of A to 100.

Above technique is simple, fast. It clearly works for 1D-list.

I want to know if there is a method for **2D-list**, that slightly modified the above example for 1D.

Here is my trial :

```
A = {{91, 34, 82, 61, 6}, {34, 1400, 48, 60, 56}, {99, 72, 7500, 43, 73}, {44, 47, 4, 68, 94}, {2, 72, 61, 35, 5000}};

Position[A, _?(Mod[#, 100] == 0 &), {2}]
{{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}}

A[[Delete[#, 0]]] & /@ {{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}}
{1400, 7500, 5000}

A[[Delete[#, 0]]] & /@ {{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}} = {9999, 9999, 9999};
(*My trial has failed. No output with an error message*)
```

If there is no 1D-analogue of 2D, what would be simple, fast method for 2D ?

A related post (about the performance of 1D case) :

[Applying f for a part of list (MapAt is slow)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264689/applying-f-for-a-part-of-list-mapat-is-slow)

+-+-+-+-+-+- After Nasser's and Michael E2's answer +-+-+-+-+-+-+-

Thank you, answerers. **Nasser's method** is standard method and **Micahel E2's method** is another method, also **I found yet another** method. I tested it for large case :

`kamo` = 10000 rows/10000 columns of integers below 10000
`ramo` = list of positions of kamo that we want to replace (50% of kamo, namely 50000000 numbers will be replaced)
`pamo` = we will replace 50% of kamo with pamo.

Rather surprisingly, in my PC (Mathematica V12.2),

Imda K's method : **4.8** seconds
Michael E2's method : **187** seconds
Nasser's standard method : krenel crashes

Screenshot:
[image]

```
SeedRandom[1234]; kamo = RandomInteger[10000, {10000, 10000}];
ramo = RandomSample[Tuples[Range[10000], 2], 10000^2/2];
pamo = RandomInteger[10000, 10000^2/2];

(kamo2 = Join @@ kamo;
  ramo2 = 10000 (#[[1]] - 1) + #[[2]] & /@ ramo;
  kamo2[[ramo2]] = pamo;
  kamo3 = Partition[kamo2, 10000];) // Timing


MapThread[
  Function[{pos, val}, 
   With[{part = Sequence @@ pos}, kamo[[part]] = val]], {ramo, pamo}]; //Timing

ReplacePart[kamo, AssociationThread[ramo, pamo]]; // Timing (*This may crash kernel *)
```

In the above case, each element of `kamo` had the same length, 10000. But what if they had different lengths ? Well, I am sure it doesn't get in the way to use my method. And I think this method can be generalized to list of complicated structure. But the thing that makes me crave the most is.. Wolfram company can do something about this? (**Upgrade the performance of** `ReplacePart`)

Comment: As [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) has commented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7224/106#comment20778_7224) "The big problem with ReplacePart is that it copies entire list rather than modify a part in-place".  Your 1D methods _modifiy in place_. Are you specifically looks for an equivalent method for 2D list that modifies the original list (as does the Michael E2 [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269321/106)), or do you want a copy where the original list is unaltered?

Comment: Your method is very nice, and certainly very fast, and cleverly uses modification-in-place to make the changes to a flattened copy. It does not modify the original list, but returns a new list (both `Join` and `Partition` will produce new lists?) but it is much faster (as you have shown) than both `ReplacePart` and the modification-in-place methods, and IMO you should write it up as a separate answer.

Comment: I (naively?) implemented your method as follows: `g[list2D_,positions_,newvals_]:=Module[{
    len=Dimensions[list2D][[2]], listFlat=Flatten@list2D},positionsFlat = len (#[[1]] - 1) + #[[2]] & /@ positions; listFlat[[positionsFlat]] = newvals;
    Partition[listFlat, len] ]`

Comment: On my system the above is about 25X faster than `Scan[(kamo[[Sequence@@#[[1]]]]=#[[2]])&,Transpose[{ramo,pamo}]];` (which modifies in place) using the example you provide

Answer (score 14):

Another option is to use `ReplacePart`

```
(A = {{91, 34, 82, 61, 6}, {34, 1400, 48, 60, 56}, {99, 72, 7500, 43, 
     73}, {44, 47, 4, 68, 94}, {2, 72, 61, 35, 5000}}) // MatrixForm
idx = {{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}};
ReplacePart[A, idx -> 9999] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`ReplacePart` Takes as second argument the positions to change and the value to change these to.

If you want different value for each position instead of the same value like the above, you can use the syntax

```
ReplacePart[A, {{2, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} -> 2, {5, 5} -> 33}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 12):

```
aa = {
 {91,   34,   82, 61,    6},
 {34, 1400,   48, 60,   56},
 {99,   72, 7500, 43,   73},
 {44,   47,    4, 68,   94},
 {2,    72,   61, 35, 5000}};

MapThread[Function[{pos, val},
   With[{part = Sequence @@ pos}, aa[[part]] = val]
   ],
  {{{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}},
   {9999, 9999, 9999}}];

aa
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
m =
  {{91, 34, 82, 61, 6},
   {34, 1400, 48, 60, 56},
   {99, 72, 7500, 43, 73},
   {44, 47, 4, 68, 94},
   {2, 72, 61, 35, 5000}};

idx = {{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}};
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> 100, idx] @ m
```

returns

```
{{91, 34, 82, 61, 6}, 
{34, 100, 48, 60, 56}, 
{99, 72, 100, 43, 73}, 
{44, 47, 4, 68, 94}, 
{2, 72, 61, 35, 100}}
```

Using `MapAt`

```
MapAt[100 &, idx] @ m
```

(* same result *)

Answer (score 2):

```
m =
  {{91, 34, 82, 61, 6},
   {34, 1400, 48, 60, 56},
   {99, 72, 7500, 43, 73},
   {44, 47, 4, 68, 94},
   {2, 72, 61, 35, 5000}};

idx = {{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}};
```

---

Using `SubsetMap`:

```
SubsetMap[100 + Subtract[#, #] &, m, idx] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  91 & 34 & 82 & 61 & 6 \\
>  34 & 100 & 48 & 60 & 56 \\
>  99 & 72 & 100 & 43 & 73 \\
>  44 & 47 & 4 & 68 & 94 \\
>  2 & 72 & 61 & 35 & 100 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$