# Why CompilationTarget->"C" doesn't improve computation time

Tags: compile, function-compile

I wrote a simple code to test the computation time under `CompilationTarget->"C"`. I get barely any improvement on the computation time from `mathKernel` computation time.

The code is as following ..

```
binarysearch = 
  Compile[{{givenvalue, _Real}, {givenarray, _Integer, 1}},
   Module[{rowmin, rowmax, rowmid, tempvalue, positionofval = 0, 
     valuemin, valuemax},
    rowmin = 1;
    rowmax = Length[givenarray];
    tempvalue = IntegerPart[givenvalue];
    If[rowmax == 1,
     If[tempvalue == givenarray[[1]], positionofval = 1];
     ];
    While[rowmin < rowmax,
     valuemin = givenarray[[rowmin]];
     valuemax = givenarray[[rowmax]];
     If[tempvalue > valuemax || tempvalue < valuemin,
      Break[];
      ];
     If[tempvalue == valuemin,
      positionofval = rowmin;
      Break[];
      ];
     If[tempvalue == valuemax,
      positionofval = rowmax;
      Break[];
      ];
     If[tempvalue > valuemin && tempvalue < valuemax,
      If[rowmax - rowmin <= 1,
       Break[];
       ];
      rowmid = IntegerPart[(rowmin + rowmax)/2];
      If[tempvalue >= givenarray[[rowmid]],
       rowmin = rowmid,
       rowmax = rowmid;
       ];
      ];
     ];
    positionofval
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

The computation time is as follows

```
In[583]:= Do[binarysearch[2.493699`*^6, array], {100000}] // Timing

Out[583]= {1.09763, Null}
```

`array` is

```
array={256265,260105,261889,341249,492033,579329,779521,1195009,1270529,1346049,1510401,2730497,2863105,5436929,8972034,8972290,9448962,9620226,9959170,9959938,10400002,10400258,10401026,10401538,10402562,10402818,10403074,10404610,10404866,10405122,10405890,10406146,10406402,10406658,10409218,10409474,10411266,10411522,10411778,10412546,10412802,10413058,10413314,10413570,10413826,10416642,10416898,10417154,10417410,10417666,10418690,10418946,10419202,10419458,10419970,10420738,10420994,10421250,10421762,10422018,10422274,10422530,10422786,10423042,10423810,10424066,10424322,10424578,10424834,10425090,10425346,10425602,10426114,10426370,10426626,10427138,10427394,10427650,10427906,10428162,10428418,10428674,10428930,10429186,10429442,10429698,10430210,10430466,10430722,10430978,10431234,10432258,10432514,10433026,10433282,10433538,10433794,10434050,10434306,10434562,10435074,10435842,10436098,10436354,10436610,10436866,10437122,10437378,10437634,10437890,10438146,10438402,10438658,10439426,10439682,10440194,10440706,10440962,10441218,10441986,10442242,10442498,10443010,10443266,10443778,10444034,10444290,10444546,10444802,10445314,10445570,10446338,10447362,10449410,10449666,10449922,10450178,10450434,10450690,10450946,10451202,10451458,10654466,10654722,10654978,10655234,10655490,10655746,10656002,10656258,10656514,10657282,10658050,10658306,10658562,10658818,10659330,10659842,10660098,10660354,10660610,10660866,10661122,10661378,10661634,10661890,10662146,10662402,10663426,10663682,10663938,10664706,10664962,10665218,10665474,10666754,10667010,10667522,10667778,10668034,10670338,10671106,10673154,10673410,10673666,10673922,10674178,10674946,10675202,10675458,10676994,10677250,10677506,10677762,10678018,10678274,10680834,10681090,10681346,10681602,10682626,10682882,10683138,10683394,10684930,10686466,10686978,10687234,10688770,10689026,10689538,10690818,10691074,10691330,10692098,10692354,10694402,10695682,10695938,10696194,10696450,10696706,10698242,10699266,10700034,10700290,10700802,10701570,10702594,10702850,10703362,10703618,10703874,10704642,10704898,10705154,10705410,10705666,10705922,10706178,10708226,10708482,10710018,10710274,10712066,10712322,10713858,10715138,10715394,10716418,10716674,10716930,10717442,10717698,10720514,10720770,10723586,10723842,10725890,10726658,10726914,10727170,10730242,10731010,11316738,11317250,11317506,11319810,11320834,11324930,11325698,11326722,11326978,11333890,11334146,11334402,11334658,11337986,11338242,11342338,11342594,11351554,11351810,11352066,11352322,11355138,11355394,11359490,11359746,11360770,11361026,11363586,11363842,11364866,11365122,11365634,11365890,11366658,11366914,11368450,11368706,11371266,11371522,11374850,11375106,11376898,11379714,11381506,11382786,11383554,11383810,11384066,11384834,11385602,11390210,11390466,11390722,11391234,11394050,11395586,11396098,11396354,11396610,11396866,11397122,11397378,11403266,11403522,11404802,11405826,11406594,11406850,11407106,11407362,11407618,11408642,11412738,11413250,11414018,11414786,11415298,11415554,11415810,11416066,11416834,11417090,12321794,12327426,12337154,12342530,12346626,12352514,12704514,12708098,12708354,12708610,12709890,12710146,12710658,12710914,12712706,12712962,12713218,12713474,12713730,12713986,12715266,12715522,12715778,12716034,12716290,12716546,12716802,12717314,12717826,12718082,12718338,12719106,12719362,12720386,12721410,12721666,12721922,12722178,12722434,12722690,12722946,12723202,12723458,12723714,12723970,12724226,12724482,12724738,12727042,12730626,12730882,12731138,12731394,12731650,12731906,12732674,12732930,12733186,12733442,12733698,12733954,12734978,12735490,12735746,12737026,12737282,12738306,12738562,12738818,12739074,12748034,12748290,12773890,12774146,12784898,12785410,12788482,12789250,12808450,12808706,12835586,12835842,12840706,12840962,12841218,12842754,12846082,12846338,14147074,14150146,18628354,18630658,18630914,18631682,18631938,18634754,18635010,18637058,18637314,18637570,18637826,18640130,18640386,18640898,18641154,18641922,18646274,18647042,18647298,18647810,18648066,18648322,18648578,18649090,18649346,18650114,18650370,18670082,18670338,18670594,18670850,18672642,18672898,18673666,18673922,18674178,18699010,18699266,18701314,18701570,18703362,18703618,26675714,26675970,26711554,26711810,26712066,26712322,26714370,26714626,26714882,26715138,26715394,26715650,26715906,26716162,26716418,26716674,26716930,26717186,26717442,26717698,26717954,26718210,26994178,26994434,26994690,26994946,26995202,26995458,26995714,26995970,26996226,26996482,26996738,26996994,26997250,26997506,26997762,26998018,26998274,26998530,26998786,26999042,27827458,27827714,27827970,27828226,27828482,27828738,27828994,27829250,27829506,27829762,27830018,27830274,27830530,27830786,27831042,27831298,27831554,27831810,27832066,27832322,27832578,27832834,27833090,27833346,27833602,27833858,27834114,27834370,27834626,27879426,27879682,27896834,27897090,27897346,27897602,27897858,27898114,27898370,27898626,27898882,27899138,27899394,29758722,29758978,29759234,29759490,29759746,29760002,29760258,29760514,29760770,29761026,29761282,29761538,29761794,29762050,29762306,29762562,29762818,29763074,29763330,29763586,29763842,29764098,29764354,29764610,29764866,29765122,29765378,29765634,29765890,29766146,29766402,29766658,29766914,29767170,29767426,29767682,29767938,29768194,29768450,29768706,29768962,29769218,30484226,30484482,30485762,30486018,30486274,30486530,30486786,30487042,30487298,30487554,30487810,30488066,30488322,30488578,30488834,30489090,30489346,30489602,30489858,30490114,30490370,30490626,30490882,30491138,30491394,30491650,30491906,30492162,30492418,30492674,30492930,30493186,30493442,30493698,30493954,30494210,30494466,30494722,30494978,30495234,30495490,30495746,38241026,38241282,38241538,38241794,38242050,38242306,38242562,38242818,38243074,38243330,38243586,38243842,38244098,38244354,38244610,38244866,38245122,38245378,38245634,38245890,38246146,38246402,38246658,38246914,38247170,38247426,38247682,38247938,38248194,38248450,38248706,38248962,38249218,38249474,38249730,38249986,38250242,38250498,38250754,38251010,38251266,38251522};
```

When `CompilationTarget -> "C"` is omitted, the computation time comes out to be

```
In[588]:= Do[binarysearch[2.493699`*^6, array], {100000}] // Timing

Out[588]= {1.56063, Null}
```

The same code, when written in `C++`, gives 40 times improvement on the computation time (0.028 sec).

`givenvalue` is not in the array, so that it runs the full loop. In the example, given in `mathDocumentation`, `CompilationTarget -> "C"` gives 20 times improvement in the computation time over `mathKernel` computation time.

Can any one let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Please also keep in mind that [`FuntionCompile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionCompile.html) produces [faster](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264689/applying-f-for-a-part-of-list-mapat-is-slow/264707#264707) code than the `Compile`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Additional to your (maybe a bit too thorough) safety checks, *Mathematica* injects quite many more bound checks for the calls to `Part` in order to avoid segfaults.

Since you can provide guarantees for `rowmin`, `rowmax` and `rowmid`, you can skip the safety checks at least for the read operations (you don't have any write operations) by replacing

```
givenarray[[i]]
```

with the undocumented

```
Compile`GetElement[givenarray, i]
```

and(!) by supplying also the option `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` to `Compile`. If you want to see what difference this makes (and what code monstrosities `Mathematica` generates at times) you can look at the C code by using

```
ExportString[binarysearch, "C"]
```

The many safety checks (and maybe also the translation of loops into goto statements) make it hard for the compiler to vectorize the loops. (But vectorization would not be useful in case of a binary search, anyways.)

Moreover, the `Do` construct is typically very, very slow compared to a loop in C/C++. You can avoid it a little by adding the option `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` and to call it on a packed array of arguments. Adding also `Parallelization -> True` allows *Mathematica* to run the loop in parallel (which does not help much here).

To avoid (very unlikely) integer overflows, I would suggest to compute `rowmid` as follows:

```
rowmid = rowmin + Quotient[(rowmax - rowin), 2];
```

This is how this could look like:

```
binarysearch1 = 
  Compile[{{givenvalue, _Real}, {givenarray, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Module[{rowmin, rowmax, rowmid, tempvalue, positionofval = 0, 
     valuemin, valuemax}, rowmin = 1;
    rowmax = Length[givenarray];
    tempvalue = IntegerPart[givenvalue];
    If[rowmax == 1, 
     If[tempvalue == Compile`GetElement[givenarray, 1], 
       positionofval = 1];];
    While[rowmin < rowmax, 
     valuemin = Compile`GetElement[givenarray, rowmin];
     valuemax = Compile`GetElement[givenarray, rowmax];
     If[tempvalue > valuemax || tempvalue < valuemin, Break[];];
     If[tempvalue == valuemin, positionofval = rowmin;
      Break[];];
     If[tempvalue == valuemax, positionofval = rowmax;
      Break[];];
     If[tempvalue > valuemin && tempvalue < valuemax, 
      If[rowmax - rowmin <= 1, Break[];];
      rowmid = IntegerPart[(rowmin + rowmax)/2];
      If[tempvalue >= Compile`GetElement[givenarray, rowmid], 
       rowmin = rowmid, rowmax = rowmid;];];];
    positionofval],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Test example:

```
rand = RandomReal[MinMax@array, 1000000];

pos = Table[binarysearch[r, array], {r, rand}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
pos1 = Table[binarysearch1[r, array], {r, rand}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
pos1par = binarysearch1[rand, array]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

pos == pos1
pos == pos1par
```

Running this on my 10-Core Apple M1 (of which *Mathematica* effectively uses only the 8 performance cores) and with `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` set in the original `binarysearch` yields the following timings:

> 1.06696
>
> 0.12087
>
> 0.058534
>
> True
>
> True

Also remember, there is some overhead for the communication between *Mathematica* and the compiled library. For example, there is some (not absolutely necessary) heavy copying going on for returning the array of results.

In total I agree that this is a bit disappointing compared to plain C++. That's why I got into the habit of coding performance critical routines directly in C++ and use *LibraryLink* to communicate with *Mathematica*.